# How to decode this integer format?

Tags: python, decode, decoding

I am trying to interpret data from a sensor (Polar H10 ECG sensor).

The data spec indicates that the string "68 00 00" corresponds to microVolts(104).  I can see in python that:

```
int('68', 16) == 104
```

However, I'm struggling to understand what to do with the other two bytes.  Are these decimal places?

The data spec can be seen [here](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/master/technical_documentation/Polar_Measurement_Data_Specification.pdf). According to the spec (page 5) the first 10 elements of this string represent status and timestamp, not data:

> [00 EA 1C AC CC 99 43 52 08 00 68 00 00 58 00 00 46 00 00 3D 00 00 32 00 00 26 00 00 16 00 00 04 00 00 ...]
>
> 00=ECG, EA 1C AC CC 99 43 52 08 = last sample timestamp in nanoseconds, 00 = ECG frameType, sample0 = [68 00 00] microVolts(104) , sample1, sample2, ....

A sample of the raw data is also pasted below.

```
00 8a c1 44 93 c4 45 52 08 00 3f 00 00 24 00 00 1a 00 00 1f 00 00 22 00 00 22 00 00 22 00 00 27 00 00 29 00 00 22 00 00 46 00 00 40 01 00 f3 02 00 47 04 00 40 04 00 08 02 00 3d ff ff c7 fe ff 62 ff ff 3f ff ff 5a ff ff bc ff ff c8 ff ff cd ff ff f4 ff ff fc ff ff f7 ff ff 02 00 00 09 00 00 04 00 00 09 00 00 1a 00 00 29 00 00 38 00 00 49 00 00 5c 00 00 70 00 00 81 00 00 97 00 00 b0 00 00 cd 00 00 ea 00 00 08 01 00 25 01 00 40 01 00 51 01 00 5d 01 00 60 01 00 53 01 00 36 01 00 00 01 00 b2 00 00 55 00 00 00 00 00 bc ff ff 89 ff ff 62 ff ff 4e ff ff 4e ff ff 4e ff ff 53 ff ff 5f ff ff 64 ff ff 66 ff ff 73 ff ff 7c ff ff 81 ff ff 8e ff ff 9a ff ff 9a ff ff a1 ff ff a8 ff ff a8 ff ff
```

How do I convert these three-byte samples into a series of numbers correctly?

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: This is a question about the data spec, not Python.

Comment: Is there a better tag I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to know if `40 42 0F` was the encoding for 1 volt. I suspect little endian. As `68 00 00` is `104mV` rather than `00 00 68` which would lead one to the big endian.

Comment: Thank you, Dan.  I appreciate your help!